# Python - color DF cell by hex value in cell

Tags: python, pandas, colors

I have a data frame that contains hex values in two columns. I would like to visualize the hex value with color swatches either by coloring the cell itself or adding a column with a color swatch. Example table is below.

| hex1 | hex 2 |
| --- | --- |
| #dcddde | #ffba00 |
| #954eff | #b889ff |

Desired output is as follows

[image]

or

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DataFrame.style`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html) is what you're after:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"hex1":["#dcddde", "#954eff"], "hex2":["#ffba00","#b889ff"]})

df.style.applymap(lambda hex_color: f"background-color: {hex_color}")
```